# JQuery UI Dialog - no scroll bars in IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, scrollbar, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm displaying a large amount of information in a JQuery UI Dialog box, which works great in every browser except IE; in IE the vertical scroll bars never appear, stretching the dialog way below the page.  In all other browsers the box automatically adds scroll bars, preventing the box from changing size.

I'm explicitly setting the height when I create the dialog.  I've also tried changing the height explicitly after creating the dialog, as in

```
$('#dialogID').dialog( ... ).height('600');
```

to no avail.  I've messed around with the !DOCTYPE, also in vain.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please post the rest of your code and if possible, a jsFiddle example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try to put this for the div `style=" overflow:scroll"`

Comment: Thanks for the response, but all this does is show grey-ed out scroll bars.

Comment: _Actually_ this did work!  It just needed to be combined with a `height: 475px;` css attribute.  Thanks for the suggestion!